# Apache 2.4 AuthType none on virtual subdirectory

Tags: apache, authentication, location, subdirectory, apache2.4

I need to have an entire site require auth except for a single virtual directory. I have the following in my config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Location />
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "protected site authentication required."
            AuthUserFile /home/me/.htpasswd
            Require valid-user
    </Location>

    <Location /foo>
            AuthType None
            Require all granted
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Why does this not work? I just want to require auth on everything except the /foo location.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways around it. The easiest, and possibly most hackish one, would be to replace Location with LocationMatch and use a negative lookahead, which basically says "do auth for everything that does not start with "/foo(/)":

```
    <LocationMatch "^/(?!foo/?).*$">
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "protected site authentication required."
            AuthUserFile /home/me/.htpasswd
            Require valid-user
    </LocationMatch>
```